# How can I modify the MySQL query to work without the WHERE?

Tags: mysql

The following query will go through my table and put append a numeric value to one of my columns.  This numeric value will increase by 1 for every row, so it will result in something like `jsmith, jsmith1, jsmith2, jsmith3`.  Currently I have to put a where clause such as `Where external_id = 'jsmith'` to update everyone with the external_id jsmith, but I want to avoid having to put the where because there could be multiple external id's, so in a nutshell, when I run this update, I would like it to produce something like `jsmith, jsmith1, jsmith2, brobert, brobert1, brobert2, pmorris, pmorris1, pmorris2, pmorris3` :

```
UPDATE ( SELECT t.id
              , t.external_id
              , CONCAT(t.external_id,case s.seq when 0 then '' else s.seq end) AS new_external_id
           FROM ( SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS seq
                       , m.id
                    FROM Header m
                    JOIN (SELECT @i := -2) i
                   ORDER BY m.id
                ) s
           JOIN Header t
             ON t.id = s.id
            WHERE t.external_id = 'jsmith' -- Exclude this
          ORDER BY t.id
       ) r
  JOIN Header u
    ON u.id = r.id
   SET u.external_id = r.new_external_id;
```

Comment: Is it a one shot operation or a query you'll have to execute now and then ?

Comment: This would be run one time.  With the above, it will append 1,2,3,4..., but after that I have to manually fix the data.